# Is there way to make my list view constant of height when I add LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I currently have problem on my layout xml, I want to list all the records on my xml layout however there is a such thing when I add another Linear Layout my ListView getting smaller, I really don't understand why the height of my list view adjusting every time I add the Linear Layout. I will show you guys my actual results and the goal I wanted.

**Goal: Make the List View height consistent.**

First Output:

[image: First Output]

As you can see there is **3 Open** If I add one Open the list view height will adjust the height automatically.

Second Output:

[image: Second Output]

Linear Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_green_300"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:textColor="@color/transparent"/>
    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:text=" Open"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:textColor="@color/transparent"/>
    
</LinearLayout>
```

List View:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/play_choice_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Appended List View:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/grey_900"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/play_id"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_grey_blue"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/transparent"
        android:text="33" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="1dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/red_600"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
            
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Win."
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/green_500"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
            
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="9,777.50"
            android:textColor="@color/transparent"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="21,153.50"
            android:textColor="@color/transparent"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope someone helps me with this. Thank you.

Comment: Use RecyclerView. It's better than ListView and you'll probably get someone you help you more easily: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: hi Augusto thank you for suggestion.

Comment: After changing to `RecyclerView`, if your problem persist, just edit your question and I'll be glad to help :D

Comment: @AugustoCarmo i made changes i made my list view to recyclerview. but still same problem

Comment: post the code with RecyclerView, please :D

Answer (score 0):

I think your Appended List View root LinearLayout height should be wrap content

Comment: it not works. if i adjust the linear layout height to wrap content. it display 1 data only.